# htaccess modrewrite to rename directory for SEF

Tags: .htaccess, directory, rename, mask

I'm wanting to change directory /rooms to show the name /gear for SEF without having to go through and change the directory name in our script. Note: the directory "gear" does not exist.

For example I want to change:
site/private/rooms/new
to say
site/private/gear/new

My current htaccess says:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /(.*)/rooms([^\ ]+)? [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/gear%2 [L,R]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/gear(/.*)?$ /$1/rooms$2 [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [PT,L]
```

And it takes me exactly to the directory that I want site.com/gear/new
However, I get a 404 error. I believe because there is no content there? I even tried duplicating folder /rooms and renaming it /gear and I still get a 404.

When the code is:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [PT,L]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

It takes you to site/private/rooms/new and it displays the content with showing /index.php 
Do you think this could be what's creating the problem? The reason why it won't show site.com/gear/new might be because it doesn't display the /index.php?

Comment: Please note that the second rule is also `[NC]` not `[NC,L]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine ON

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /(.*)/rooms([^\ ]+)? [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/gear%2 [L,R]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/gear(/.*)?$ /$1/rooms$2 [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [PT,L]
```

Your rules don't match because

```
 RewriteRule ^/rooms(.*)?$ /gear$1 [R]
```

- The path never contains a leading slash (when using a `RewriteRule` in an `.htaccess`). Hence `/rooms` would never match.
- Your rules ignore that the URL path starts with `private`. They match on `rooms` and `gear` as the first path directory instead.

Comment: Thanks so much for the response!! I tried what you put & it's getting closer, but when testing it, it forwards you to private/gear/new%2520HTTP/1.1?/gear/new HTTP/1.1

Comment: It might have to do with internal/external requests? I don't actually have a "gear" folder so I believe it has to be external... I'm still researching what that actually means though

Comment: so like this?    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /(.*)/rooms(/.*)? [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/gear%2 [L,R]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/gear(/.*)?$ /$1/rooms([^\ ]+)? [NC,L]

Comment: I'm sorry for not getting it, this is the strangest language I've seen :)

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me with this!! Haha, it's way over my head

Comment: Is there something in the code above that makes the "/gear/new" show up twice in the URL?

Comment: I'm just checking if any of your previous rules might be interfering. Could you post your current htaccess with my rules included in your question again? I need to check the flow.

Comment: Please, move your `index.php` rule to the end as in my update.

Comment: Please note that I had also changed `[NC,L]` to `[NC]` for the 2nd `RewriteRule`. Could you have possibly missed that?